# Extract information from DTD

Tags: java, extract, dtd

In java i want a list of attributes from an element in a dtd file.

DTD Example:

```
<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
```

I need something like `getChilds(note)`...

Is it posibility to do this? I need a dtd parser but i can not find one who provide this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a SAX parser, with a [`DeclHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html).

> To set the `DeclHandler` for an XML reader, use the `setProperty` method with the property name `http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler` and an object implementing `DeclHandler`. If the reader does not report declaration events, it will throw a `SAXNotRecognizedException` when you attempt to register the handler.

The `model` argument in method `DeclHandler.elementDecl(String name, String model)` for `name="note"` would be `(to,from,heading,body)`.